# Apache poi excel writer works in ide but not in fat jar? java.io.IOException: Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML str

Tags: java, excel, maven, apache-poi

The code works perfectly fine in IDE but not in normal `.jar` or in `fat .jar`? The program works perfectly fine otherwise. Also `non-fat .jar` doesn't work either.

The error is:

```
Jun 08, 2021 11:43:14 AM DataManagers.ExcelWriter$WriterThread run
SEVERE: null
java.io.IOException: Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream or you haven't provide the poi-ooxml*.jar in the classpath/modulepath - FileMagic: OOXML, having providers: [org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbookFactory@405294c8]
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.wp(WorkbookFactory.java:300)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:199)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:163)
        at DataManagers.ExcelWriter$WriterThread.run(ExcelWriter.java:61)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

and this error repeats 3 times.

And my `maven pom` is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Implementation</groupId>
    <artifactId>Implementation</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>

            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>

            <version>11.0.2</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mmarquee</groupId>
            <artifactId>ui-automation</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.3</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>  
        
       

        <dependency> <!-- Excel -->
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>   <!-- End of excel -->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.cdimascio</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-dotenv</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>    
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.15.1
            </version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
            <artifactId>saxon-dom</artifactId>
            <version>8.7</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- get all project dependencies -->
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <!-- MainClass in mainfest make a executable jar -->
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>UserInterface.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>

                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/UserInterface/*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.3</version>
            </plugin>  
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
             
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
                
            <!--            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>xls</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>xls</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>-->

            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>UserInterface.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>       

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>UserInterface.Main</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>     
        </plugins>   
    </build>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <name>Implementation</name>
</project>
```

some sample of the code which writes:

```
FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(file);
wb = WorkbookFactory.create(f);
s = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
initialiseExcel();
f.close();
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
initialiseExcel();
Row row = s.createRow(0);
Cell cell = row.createCell(1);
cell.setCellValue("Pvm");    wb.write(fOut);
fOut.close();
...
```

I have searched for fixes but everyone seems to be saying fat jar fixes it but i'm running the fat jar and the problem still comes up and I don't really have any clue what to do?

Thanks a lot for anyone who cares to help.

Comment: Bizarre it works in ide with .xlsx but in jar it only works with .xsl???

Comment: Make sure you include all the resources and service files from the Apache POI jars when you build the fat jar?

Comment: Did you finally find a solution?

Comment: Nope, I haven't found a solution. I don't know much about maven syntax but I think mine should include everything but It doesn't work, possibly there is some apache poi dependency that should be added or somehow my pom excludes some dependency but yea I don't know. I'm just using xls files for now since they work but if someone finds a solution I would be glad.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution.
Service loader use files in `META-INF/services` for know available providers.
When you build your fat jar, providers file from `org.apache.poi:poi` and `org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml` are not merged and only one is in your fat-jar.
A simple solution is to add a built-in transformer in `maven-shade-plugin` which do the merges:

```xml
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

UPD. Add this code to main function of your programm.
Solution from: https://github.com/Mararsh/MyBox/issues/1101

```
WorkbookFactory.addProvider(new HSSFWorkbookFactory());
WorkbookFactory.addProvider(new XSSFWorkbookFactory());
```

Old post (don't read):

I could not solve this problem on POI 5.0.0 and above, the only working solution is to use the 4.1.2 dependencies.

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

The solution from @Ankur Mahajan, unfortunately, also doesn't work for some OLE2 files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dependency-plugin` to generate all dependencies in a separate directory before the package phase and then include that in the classpath of the manifest by `maven-jar-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>theMainClass_ChangeMe_withPackage</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Alternatively use `${project.build.directory}/classes/lib` as output directory to integrate all jar files into the main jar, but then you will need to add custom classloading code to load the jars. I hope this will help as `maven-assembly` plugin is not working with this scanerio.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.  my Java program could read xlsx files in IDE to import data, but the Jar errored out.  from my limited Java knowledge, it seems a class used to read big size Excel file is not packaged by Maven. The simple addition to POM to add the transformer solved the problem.

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
```

Comment: Where did you add this line ? if you don't mind me asking under configuration > Transformers tags right ?